# How I cut my orange - spherical volume integral

Tags: integration, volume, spherical-geometry

I cut my orange in six eatable pieces, following some rules. My orange is a perfect sphere, and there is a cylindrical volume down through my orange, that is not eatable.

[image: Picture of cut out of orange]

In the diagram, the orange with radius, $R$ is shown as seen from the top. The circle with radius, $r$ is the non-eatable center. All lines are vertical cuts to be made. The red area is the final waste. Many of the cuts are tangential to the non-eatable center to minimize waste. The pieces are labeled $1\ldots6$. and the angles for each pieces are labeled $\alpha_{1\ldots7}$.

[image: Diagram of cuts]

I want to optimize my cuts, so that the volume of the pieces are similar. I denote the volume of piece $n$ as $V_n$. It can be done, so that $V_1=V_2=V_3$ and $V_4=V_5=V_6$.

**The first half:** The volume of $V_1+V_2+V_3$ can easily be calculated from [the spherical cap formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap):
$(V_1+V_2+V_3) = \pi/3(R-r)^2(2R+r)$

To calculate $\alpha_1$, all I need is the volume, $V_1$ of the skewed spherical wedge as a function of $\alpha_1$. How do I set up this integral?

**The second half:** Making $V_4=V_5=V_6$ is a lot more complicated, but I would like to know how to make the volume integral that allows me to calculate volumes like $V_4$ and $V_5$.

**The final cut:** My intuition says, that making the final cut, where the waste is separated from piece 6. is best done by making $\alpha_6 = \alpha_7$. Does that really minimize the waste?

Comment: Is the vertex of 2. assumed to be at the midpoint of the tangent line, or do we need to prove that?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Yes - the vertex of 1. 2. and 3. is at the midpoint of the tangent line.

Comment: The points 5, 6 and the top intersect are colinear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For practical purposes assume that $r\ne0,R$.

**Proposition 1.**
Suppose we cut in a straight line between 1. and 2. at angle $\alpha_1$. Then $$V_1(\alpha_1)=\frac\pi6(R-r)^2(2R+r)+\frac13q(\alpha_1;R,r)$$ where \begin{align}q(\alpha_1;R,r)&=(3R^2r\cos\alpha_1-r^3\cos^3\alpha_1)\arctan\frac{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}{r\sin\alpha_1}\\&\quad-2R^3\arctan\frac{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}{R\tan\alpha_1}-\frac12r^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\sin2\alpha_1.\end{align}

This formula has intuitive interpretations. Geometrically, as $\alpha_1\to0$, the cut approaches the tangent line so we should expect $V_1\to0$. Indeed, we have \begin{align}q(+\infty;R,r)&=(3R^2r-r^3-2R^3)\frac\pi2=-\frac\pi2(R-r)^2(2R+r).\end{align}
Also, when $\alpha_1=\pi/2$, we have $V_1=(V_1+V_2+V_3)/2=\pi(R-r)^2(2R+r)/6$ using the spherical cap formula; by direct computation, $q(\pi/2;R,r)=0$ and we are left with the same result.

**Proposition 2.** Rather unintuitively, $V_1=V_2=V_3$ is impossible when $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3$.

I have [asked on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437371/dividing-a-spherical-cap-into-n-equal-wedges) whether this can be extended to $n>3$ partitions; that is, whether the only spherical cap whose $n$ wedges have the same angles and volumes is the hemisphere.

**Remark 3.** Note that the integrals for $V_4$ and $V_5$ can be set up analogously, since it involves cutting by two planes. Since $V_6$ involves cutting by three planes, we cannot directly apply the same method. I haven't worked out the bounds yet.

**Question 4.** If the spherical cap is divided into $n$ wedges at an angle of $\pi/n$, is $V_1=V_2=\cdots=V_n$ also impossible for $n>3$?

---

*Proof of Proposition 1:* Consider a shift in coordinates $x\to x+r$ so that the tangent line spanning 1. to 3. is $x=0$.

The volume of 1. is therefore bounded by the sphere $(x+r)^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ and the planes $x=0$ and $y=-mx$ where $\alpha_1=\pi/2-\arctan m$. Since $x=0$, we have $$-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\le z\le\sqrt{R^2-r^2}.$$ The plane $y=-mx$ meets the sphere at $(x+r)^2+m^2x^2+z^2=R^2$ so $$0\le x\le\frac{-r+\sqrt{r^2+(m^2+1)(R^2-r^2-z^2)}}{m^2+1}:=f(z).$$ Finally, by definition we obtain $$-\sqrt{R^2-(x+r)^2-z^2}\le y\le-mx$$ so the integral is thus \begin{align}V_1&=\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}\int_0^{f(z)}\left(\sqrt{R^2-(x+r)^2-z^2}-mx\right)\,dx\,dz\\&=\small\frac12\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}\left[(x+r)\sqrt{R^2-(x+r)^2-z^2}+(R^2-z^2)\arctan\frac{x+r}{\sqrt{R^2-(x+r)^2-z^2}}-mx^2\right]_0^{f(z)}\,dz.\end{align} Recalling that $f(z)$ satisfies $mf(z)=\sqrt{R^2-(f(z)+r)^2-z^2}$, the inner integral becomes $$\small mrf(z)+(R^2-z^2)\arctan\frac{f(z)+r}{mf(z)}-r\sqrt{R^2-r^2-z^2}-(R^2-z^2)\arctan\frac r{\sqrt{R^2-r^2-z^2}}.$$ Since this is a function of $z^2$, we can write $$V_1=I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4$$ where \begin{align}I_1&=\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}mrf(z)\,dz\\&=-\frac{mr^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}{m^2+1}+\frac1{m^2+1}\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}\sqrt{r^2+(m^2+1)(R^2-r^2-z^2)}\,dz\\&=\frac{mr}{2\sqrt{m^2+1}}\left[\left(\frac{r^2}{m^2+1}+R^2-r^2\right)\arctan\frac{\sqrt{(m^2+1)(R^2-r^2)}}r-r\sqrt{\frac{R^2-r^2}{m^2+1}}\right]\\\\I_2&=\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}(R^2-z^2)\arctan\frac{f(z)+r}{mf(z)}\,dz\\&=\frac16\left(\frac{mr^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}{m^2+1}+\pi(r^2+2R^2)\sqrt{R^2-r^2}-4R^3\arctan\left(\frac{m\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}R\right)\right.\\&\left.\quad\quad+\frac{mr(m^2r^2+3(m^2+1)R^2)}{(m^2+1)^{3/2}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{(m^2+1)(R^2-r^2)}}r\right)\right)\\\\I_3&=-\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}r\sqrt{R^2-r^2-z^2}\,dz=-\frac{\pi r}4(R^2-r^2)\\\\I_4&=-\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}(R^2-z^2)\arctan\frac r{\sqrt{R^2-r^2-z^2}}\,dz\\&=\frac\pi{12}\left(4R^3-3R^2r-r^3-2(2R^2+r^2)\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\right).\end{align} This reduces to $$V_1=\frac\pi6(R-r)^2(2R+r)+g(m;R,r)$$ where \begin{align}g(m;R,r)&=\frac{3m(m^2+1)R^2r-m^3r^3}{3(m^2+1)^{3/2}}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{(m^2+1)(R^2-r^2)}}r\\&\quad-\frac23R^3\arctan\frac{m\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}R-\frac{mr^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}{3(m^2+1)}\end{align} and substituting $m=\cot\alpha_1$ and $g=3q$ yields the desired result.

*Sketch proof of Proposition 2:* $V_1=V_2=V_3$ forces $$q(\alpha_1;R,r)=-\frac\pi6(R-r)^2(2R+r).$$ If the angles are equal, $\alpha_i=\pi/3$. We can eliminate both $R$ and $r$ by substituting $s=\sqrt{(1-r^2/R^2)/3}$ which gives $$\small2\arctan s+\frac{3s}4(1-3s^2)-\frac{11+3s^2}8\sqrt{1-3s^2}\arctan\frac{2s}{\sqrt{1-3s^2}}=\frac\pi6(1-\sqrt{1-3s^2})^2(2+\sqrt{1-3s^2})$$ over the range $s\in[0,1/\sqrt3]$. The case $s=0$ means $r=R$ (impossible) and the case $s=1/\sqrt3$ means $r=0$ (also impossible). In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/437361/113397), @IosifPinelis shows that the equation has no solution in $(0,1/\sqrt3)$ which proves the lemma.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will take me some days to try to understand it (some of it). If `2*R=10cm` and `2*r=1cm`, can I use your answer to calculate `\alpha_1` to nearest degree?

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, the answer is $58$ degrees. Substituting $R=5$ and $r=0.5$ into $q(\alpha;R,r)=-\pi(R-r)^2(2R+r)/6$ gives $$\left(\frac{75}2\cos\alpha_1-\frac1{64}\cos^3\alpha_1\right)\arctan\frac{\sqrt{99}}{\sin\alpha_1}-250\arctan\frac{\sqrt{99}}{10\tan\alpha_1}-\frac{\sqrt{99}}{16}\sin2\alpha_1+\frac{567}{16}\pi=0$$ The Mathematica command `FindRoot[(37.5Cos[x]-Cos[x]^3/64)ArcTan[Sqrt[99]/Sin[x]]-250ArcTan[0.1Sqrt[99]Cot[x]]-Sqrt[99]Sin[2x]/16+567Pi/16,{x,1}]` gives $$\alpha_1=1.00619\cdots\text{radians}=57.65\cdots^\circ$$

Comment: For others/completeness: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=roots+of+%2837.5Cos%5Bx%5D-Cos%5Bx%5D%5E3%2F64%29ArcTan%5BSqrt%5B99%5D%2FSin%5Bx%5D%5D-250ArcTan%5B0.1Sqrt%5B99%5DCot%5Bx%5D%5D-Sqrt%5B99%5DSin%5B2x%5D%2F16%2B567Pi%2F16

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for comment* but may give some useful ideas for setting up the integrals in spherical coordinates (cylindrical may be slightly simpler):

Make the first cut into the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2 \iff \rho=R$ along the plane $x=r \iff \rho=r\sec(\theta)\csc(\phi)$. Letting $\theta$ vary over a fixed symmetric interval, solve for $\phi$ when the plane and sphere meet to get

$$r\sec(\theta)\csc(\phi)=R \implies \sin(\phi) = \frac rR \sec(\theta)$$

In the plane $z=0$, when $\phi=\frac\pi2$, we have

$$r\sec(\theta)=R \implies \cos(\theta) = \frac rR$$

Hence the volume of the **first half** is given by the integral(s)

$$\begin{align*}
V_1+V_2+V_3&=\int_{-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)}^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)} \int_{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac rR \sec(\theta)\right)}^{\pi - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac rR \sec(\theta)\right)} \int_{r\sec(\theta)\csc(\phi)}^R \rho^2 \sin(\phi)\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta\\[1ex]
&= \frac13 \int_{-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)}^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)} \int_{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac rR \sec(\theta)\right)}^{\pi - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac rR \sec(\theta)\right)} \left(R^3\sin(\phi)-r^3\sec^3(\theta)\csc^2(\phi)\right)\,d\phi\,d\theta \\[1ex]
&= \frac23 \int_{-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)}^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)} \frac{\left(R^2\cos^2(\theta)-r^2\right)^{\frac32}}{\cos^3(\theta)}\,d\theta \\[1ex]
&= \frac{4R^3}3 \int_r^R \frac{\left(\lambda^2-r^2\right)^{\frac32}}{\lambda^3\sqrt{R^2-\lambda^2}} \, d\lambda
\end{align*}$$

which agrees with the spherical cap formula.

To isolate the volume of just the **first wedge**, it would be convenient to fix the point of tangency of the cut to the core to lie in the planes $x=r$ and $y=0$, and to know $\alpha_1$. Then we can find an equation for the plane representing the cut that forms $V_1,V_2$, $\rho_1 = \frac{r\csc(\phi)}{\cos(\theta)+\tan(\alpha_1)\sin(\theta)}=\frac{r\csc(\phi)}{\sec(\alpha_1)\cos(\theta-\alpha_1)}$.

[image]

The bounds highlighted in red (part of the very first cut) and green represent the lower and upper limits of $\rho$ - in particular, the green boundary is $\rho=\min\left(\rho_1,R\right)$. The south-southeasternmost ray is $\theta=-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)$. Let the other two be given by $\theta=\theta_1$ and $\theta=\theta_2$.

When $\theta\in\left[-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right),\theta_1\right]$, the integral takes the same the limits for $\phi$ as the integral for the first half.

When $\theta\in[\theta_1,\theta_2]$, we see the cut $\rho_1$ meets the sphere for

$$\frac{r\csc(\phi)}{\sec(\alpha_1)\cos(\theta-\alpha_1)} = R \implies \sin(\phi) = \frac{r\cos(\alpha_1)}{R\cos(\theta-\alpha_1)}$$

We find $\theta_1$ by solving for $\theta$ in the above equation when $\phi=\frac\pi2$:

$$\frac{r}{\sec(\alpha_1)\cos(\theta-\alpha_1)} = R \implies \cos(\theta-\alpha_1) = \frac rR \cos(\alpha_1) \\ \implies \theta_1 = \alpha_1-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR \cos(\alpha_1)\right)$$

We find $\theta_2$ by finding where the first cut meets the cut $\rho_1$:

$$r\sec(\theta)\csc(\phi) = \frac{r\csc(\phi)}{\sec(\alpha_1)\cos(\theta-\alpha_1)} \implies \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\cos(\theta-\alpha_1)}=\cos(\alpha_1) \\ \implies \theta_2 = 0$$

Then the integral for $V_1$ has limits

$$\int_{-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR\right)}^{\alpha_1-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR \cos(\alpha_1)\right)} \int_{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac rR \sec(\theta)\right)}^{\pi-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac rR \sec(\theta)\right)} \int_{r\sec(\theta)\csc(\phi)}^R \\
+ \int_{\alpha_1-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac rR \cos(\alpha_1)\right)}^0 \int_{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r\cos(\alpha_1)}{R\cos(\theta-\alpha_1)}\right)}^{\pi-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r\cos(\alpha_1)}{R\cos(\theta-\alpha_1)}\right)} \int_{r\sec(\theta)\csc(\phi)}^{\frac{r\csc(\phi)}{\sec(\alpha_1)\cos(\theta-\alpha_1)}}$$